# How to cache data if there is no unique identifier?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, caching

I have a spring-boot application. I have a method that gives away some content. Let's say bank customers. Let's say that bank customers are not added to the database very often. How can I **cache** this method so that the method follows a new list to the database only **when a new customer is added there**?

Sounds trivial enough, but I can't think of a mechanism.
That is, we have a method of say

```
GET /customers
```

The cache is tuned to the unique parameters in the request. Since this method has no unique parameters, the data will always be returned from the cache, even if the list of clients is added one extra.

For example, you can think of some method with a **boolean response**. It would return true when the list is updated. But this looks like a nasty solution. And it also means that **instead of one request you have to do two at once**. And if you also have authorization, authentication - that's three requests. That sounds bad.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Maybe you could consider ETags or similar mechanisms

Answer (score 0):

Where do you will store the cache? Some of them, like Redis, you can set the expiry of the cached data. So it will refresh the data for every time that you have set.

Or you can store something like 'version' in the database, and also add to cache. So everytime you add new customer, you also update the version. Then it can be used to compare the version in db and cache are same or not, if not then get new list to database and re-add to cache. But this way need to call db every time you hit the GET /customers.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to clear the cache for a method, for example using redis? For example, I have a post method for creating a customer. And a get method to return all the customers. And I want to clear the cache at the get method when I used the post method.